# Writing to Kafka topic not working but no error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I read streaming data using file source

```
parquet_sdf = spark.readStream.schema(schema).parquet(path)
```

Then I do some transformation on df

```
sdf = parquet_sdf. \
        withColumn('time', current_timestamp()). \
        withWatermark('time', '5 seconds'). \
        withColumn('country', substring('monitoringSiteIdentifier', 1, 2)). \
        where(col('resultObservationStatus') == 'A').\
        groupBy('country', 'resultObservationStatus', 'time').count()
```

And try to store it in Kafka but it does not work.

```
sdf \
        .selectExpr("CAST(country AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
        .writeStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
        .option("topic", TOPIC) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/demo") \
        .trigger(processingTime='1 seconds') \
        .start()
```

I have a script which moves files to the parquet directory path and then I run this code.
I do not get any error. But do not see any messages on the Kafka topic.
When I try the console format below it works and I can see the messages on the console

```
sdf.writeStream \
         .trigger(processingTime='1 seconds') \
         .outputMode("update") \
         .option("truncate", "false") \
         .format("console") \
         .start().awaitTermination()
```

I am not sure why it is not working in Kafka.

Comment: If you've already written to the console, then the file was already "processed", so Spark wouldn't try to write to Kafka when you restart the code.. File source also only works on atomically moved files

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Well I do not do both at once. Also before running the script I clear all the checkpointLocation and make sure it is empty and then copy the files to the readStream directory when the script is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I needed to add `.awaitTermination()` at the end for the `writeStream` method also.

```
sdf.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='1 seconds') \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
        .option("topic", TOPIC) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/demo") \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

Then before running the script I clear all the `checkpointLocation` and make sure it is empty and then copy the files to the directory from where `readStream` is reading from while the script is running and just wait in the `kafka-console-consumer` window and it started appearing.